# How to perform keypoint regression on a custom dataset in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Is it possible to use CenterNet with MobilenetV2 backbone (TF Lite compatible) to perform keypoints detection on a custom dataset? Is there a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find any tutorial?

Comment: Hi! Have you checked out this Colab notebook on Keypoint detection yet?   https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/keypoint_detection.ipynb

Comment: @ThiranjayaMunasinghe please checkout this github repo https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/Custom-keypoint-detection

Answer (score 0):

I have something for training keypoint detection model for custom dataset on Centernet model with hourglass backbone.

This github repo [Custom Keypoint Detection](https://github.com/prabhakar-sivanesan/Custom-keypoint-detection) for dataset preparation, model training and inference on **Centernet-hourglass104** keypoint detection model based on **Tensorflow Object detection API** with examples.

This could help you in training your keypoint detection model on custom dataset.

Any issues related to the project can be raised in the github itself and doubts can be cleared here.